# Duration of host unreachable by ping

Tags: time, ping, timeout

Suppose I am pinging an IP and the destination is reachable. I did some change in the network so for a few seconds the destination was unreachable. After few seconds it comes live again.

Is there any way to measure that how long it was unreachable? Figure is for better understanding.

[image: Screenshot of ping output]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just count the pings that went missing and multiply that with your ping interval, which you can explicitly set with the `-i` flag. That's as good as an estimate as it gets.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the default interval is 1 second, so (by default) the number of missing pings is the same as the number of seconds that the destination was unavailable.